# How to silently/unattended install JavaEE on Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, java

I've downloaded Java (`jdk-6u31-linux-x64.bin`) from [oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u31-oth-JPR). I run the executable, files are successfully unpacked, but then there is a message about registration and it sits at

> Press Enter to continue...

I need to be able to run this automatically from a script. Is there a straightforward way to skip or automatically dismiss this prompt?

Comment: If your Linux is Debian, you should use `java-package` to turn that `.bin` into a `.deb`. Which shouldn't display that message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
touch answers && ./jdk-6u31-linux-x64.bin < answers && rm answers
```

This command does the following:

1. `touch answers` Create an empty text file called `answers` in the current directory
2. `./jdk-6u31-linux-x64.bin < answers` Execute the Java installer and redirect stdin from the empty `answers` file
3. `rm answers` Delete the temporary file when finished
4. `&&` Combine three operation into a single line. Only execute the next command if the previous command completed successfully

Comment: When suggesting a user execute commands, it's helpful to explain what they do.

Comment: I think you want `&&` instead of `&`

Comment: `&` will run them simultaneously, `&&` will run as long as the previous exited successfully (exit code 0), and `;` will run after the previous command is finished regardless of it's exit code.

Comment: You're correct. Update to use `&&`.